# setup with submodules dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, distutils

We have a python package which is also a git repo. It depends on other python packages, themselves git repos. We made the latter git submodules of the former.
None of these are public, so no PyPI.

None of the other questions related to installing with submodule dependencies match our pattern. My question is not about finding (sub)packages with `setuptools`, nor is it about relative imports.

This is our structure:

```
package-repo/
    setup.py
    setup.cfg
    README.md
    .gitignore
    .gitmodules
    .git/
    submodule-repo/
        .git/
        .gitignore
        setup.py
        setup.cfg
        README.md
        submodule/
            __init__.py
            moduleX.py
            moduleY.py
    package/
        __init__.py
        moduleA.py
        moduleB.py
        subpackage1/
```

As is the case with requirements.txt, I naively though that something as follow would work out:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='package',
      version='0.4.1',
      description='A package depending on other self made packages',
      url='git.ownnetwork.com',
      author='wli',
      author_email='wli@',
      license='Proprietary',
      packages=['package','package.subpackage1'],
      include_package_data=True,
      python_requires='>=3.7',
    classifiers=[
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9',
    ],
      install_requires=["SQLAlchemy",
                        "pandas",
                        "./submodule-repo"])
```

It doesn't work.

An alternative is to add the submodule in `packages` and indicate its directory in `package_dir`. Well it didn't work that well, and what's the point of making a setup.py in the "submodule" if it can't be installed when installing the dependent module?
I just want it to be installed without having to put it on PyPI or create a virtual PyPI server, which is seriously overkill, or having to indicate what to do (i.e. `pip install ./submodule-repo/`) in the README.md, which is inelegant.

What's the way? Did I miss it in distutils or setuptools documentation?

Comment: How is this related to setuptools?

Comment: You want to add you private git repository to `install_requires`.

Comment: What is `dirpath` in the comment you posted to the accepted answer?  I'm trying to implement *exactly* the same thing and this looks promising. Did you avoid using an absolute path with the `git+file://` URL?

Comment: Best would have been to ask this under the accepted answer. I'll answer there

Comment: @chrisinmtown see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to specify where to install the submodule from.

```
install_requires=[
    'SQLAlchemy',
    'pandas',
     # Your private repository module
    '<dependency_name> @ git+ssh://git@github.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>@<branch>'
]
```

Comment: OK, I can see we had to rephrase the question to find appropriate answers. Using a git submodule was not the way to go for our problem. Although your response doesn't answer my specific question, it solves my problem ;) . Thanks!

Comment: Well it actually doesn't work. We even hoped `git+file://{path}` would work, but it doesn't either. It works only with pip install as documented https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#git

Comment: Last comment: following string did work when put inside : `rf'submodule @ git+file://<dirpath>{os.path.sep}submodule-repo#egg=submodule'`

Comment: Dir path is `Path(__file__).parent` for me, as the submodule is simply a git folder in the same folder as the setup.py file